# Getting Error TypeError: create_task() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given while creating google cloud tasks

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, queue, google-cloud-tasks

```
from google.cloud import tasks_v2

import json


GCP_PROJECT='test'
GCP_LOCATION='europe-west6'


def enqueue_task(queue_name, payload, process_url):
  client = tasks_v2.CloudTasksClient()
  parent = client.queue_path(GCP_PROJECT, GCP_LOCATION, queue_name)

  task = {
    'app_engine_http_request': {
      'http_method': 'POST',
      'relative_uri': process_url
    }
  }

  if payload is None:
    return False

  payload = json.dumps(payload)
  converted_payload = payload.encode()

  task['app_engine_http_request']['body'] = converted_payload
  return client.create_task(parent, task)
```

I keep getting the following error when I try to create a Google Cloud Task.
The Google App Engine Runtime used is python38. It was working fine but suddenly after deployment using gcp CLI it does not work now.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/srv/main.py", line 153, in sync_request
    queue_response = queues.enqueue_task(
  File "/srv/queues.py", line 28, in enqueue_task
    return client.create_task(parent, task)
TypeError: create_task() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The same thing has just happened to me (on live server :/). Turns out, the Cloud Tasks library has changed significantly with version 2.0.0. You can read [what you need to do to upgrade here](https://googleapis.dev/python/cloudtasks/latest/UPGRADING.html).

Your problem is in this line:

```py
client.create_task(parent, task)
```

The updated library requires to either use a dictionary as a positional argument or use keyword arguments. So this should fix it:

```py
client.create_task(parent=parent, task=task)
```

EDIT: Looking at your code now that I've made this work for myself, you will also have to change the following:

```py
# Before
parent = client.queue_path(GCP_PROJECT, GCP_LOCATION, queue_name)
# After
parent = client.queue_path(project=GCP_PROJECT, location=GCP_LOCATION, queue=queue_name)
```

and

```py
# Before
'http_method': 'POST',
# After
'http_method': tasks_v2.HttpMethod.POST,
```

Comment: Yes, this worked for me. Even I was facing it in a live environment. This seems to be a problem with google-cloud-tasks version 2.0.0. Also, downgrading the version to 1.5.0 made the code work without any change.